# Jackson annotation to put the map's key in map' POJO value

Tags: java, jackson

Desired Java:

```
class Root {

    @JsonProperty("mymap")
    private Map<String, Pojo> map;
}

class Pojo {

    @JsonAnnotationThatIHopeExists
    private String name; // set to the value of key in 'mymap'
    @JsonProperty("val1")
    private String val1;
    // and many more...
}
```

Json:

```
{
    "mymap": {
        "a": { "val1": "first val"},
        "b": { "val1": "a val" },
        "c": { "val1": "some val" }
    }
}
```

I can easily solve this problem by adding the property "name": "a"; name: "b", name: "c"; in each objects in "mymap" but I would rather not duplicate that info while still letting Jackson build me a map.
I also don't want to write a custom deserializer for this since Jackson can already do 99% of the job...

I wonder if there is a Jackson annotation I could leverage to inject the key names of "mymap" into their respective object values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the @JsonAnyGetter and @JsonAnySetter

```
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> any() {
    return map;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String name, Object value) {
    map.put(name, value);
}
```